# What is this wildflower?

Tags: identification

[image]

[image]

[image]

It grew out of nowhere. I a kind of don't dislike it. Please help me id it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plant is Queen Anne's Lace (Daucus carota) or wild carrot. If you're in the US, it's technically not a wildflower because it's not native to North America. It can be invasive, but is relatively easy to control because it's biennial and invasive by seed, not by root. If you want more of the plant, just let one or two of the flowers set seed, then collect the seed and plant them where you want them. I would definitely remove most of the seedheads, though, because you're likely to get dozens to hundreds of plants from those in your photos (remove the seeds when the flowerheads turn brownish and curl up to resemble birds' nests).

Comment: Beware that some people are sensitive to a natural fungicide produced by this plant, and contact with damp foliage may cause severe skin irritation. Also, it is susceptible to the same pests and diseases as carrots grown as vegetables, so keep the two separate in your garden!

Comment: What is this fungicide produced by wild carrot?

Comment: @alephzero, I've never heard of issues touching QAL - maybe it's more prevalent in damp climates? I wish that the hundreds+ of QALs on my land had been susceptible to ANY pest or disease - they were always quite healthy, unfortunately. We eventually eradicated 99% of them simply by deadheading them.